# Homebrew running service shows error, how to debug this?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, package-management, launch-services

When I run `brew services list` one of my services state shows `err`.
`brew services restart elasticsearch@6` for example stops and restarts with no error output and shows:

```
brew services restart elasticsearch@6
Stopping `elasticsearch@6`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `elasticsearch@6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch@6)
==> Successfully started `elasticsearch@6` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch@6)
```

But list still shows err. There's something wrong but Homebrew doesn't tell us what it is.  How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the log file in `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch.log`.

**TL;DR**

If you look at the formula definition with:

```
brew edit elasticsearch@6
```

You will find the content of the plist file used for this service, which define the output log as:

```
#{var}/log/elasticsearch.log
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Homebrew/brew/Formula:var):

> #var ⇒ Object
>
> The directory where the formula's variable files should be installed. This directory is not inside the HOMEBREW_CELLAR so it persists across upgrades.

According to the [source code](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb#L825):

```
def var
  HOMEBREW_PREFIX/"var"
end
```

You can find the `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` with:

```
brew --prefix
```

It is most likely `/usr/local`. So you will find your log file in `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch.log`.

Comment: Thanks all the errors seem related to Java, I'm MacOS Big Sur so I may see what's going on there